# Order dates/Group tasks by number of days in a cycle

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of tasks that occur once in a cycle and cycle can be repeated. Now first i had to calculate the occurrences of these tasks and order these and then pivot the resultant to get the following result in a temp table:

[image]

This data is for a cycle set, that occurs from 5th Dec 2016 to 16 Dec 2016(7 day cycle) having 5 task in each cycle and I want data to be clumped like so:

[image]

I cant think how to get the final result from first data set. As you can see in the first data set, the order of dates in the columns can be un-ordered like 9-12-2016 comes before 7-12-2016/8-12-2016 but the tasks will always occur in one specific pattern i.e 'Ecs and print label' will always come after 'inventory preview' and 'Order and receive meds'.

I can always use looping and stuff but if someone can help me find a proper query for this id be really grateful.

Here is some sample code to create the data shown above:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    CurrentOccurrenceDate DATETIME,
    TaskID INT,
    EmpID INT,
    FacName VARCHAR(50),
    Census DATETIME,
    [Cycle Drop] DATETIME,
    [ECS and Print Label] DATETIME,
    [Inventory Preview] DATETIME,
    [Order and Receive Meds] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO tasks (CurrentOccurrenceDate, TaskID, EmpID, FacName, Census, [Cycle Drop], [ECS and Print Label], [Inventory Preview], [Order and Receive Meds]) VALUES
('2016-12-05', 1, 1, '75TH TERRACE', '2016-12-05', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('2016-12-06', 2, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, '2016-12-06', NULL, NULL, NULL),
('2016-12-07', 3, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2016-12-07', NULL),
('2016-12-08', 4, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2016-12-08'),
('2016-12-09', 5, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, NULL, '2016-12-09', NULL, NULL),
('2016-12-12', 1, 1, '75TH TERRACE', '2016-12-12', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('2016-12-13', 2, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, '2016-12-13', NULL, NULL, NULL),
('2016-12-14', 3, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2016-12-14', NULL),
('2016-12-15', 4, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2016-12-15'),
('2016-12-16', 5, 1, '75TH TERRACE', NULL, NULL, '2016-12-16', NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: Will two cycles of tasks for the same `FacName` ever overlap, or will task 5 in this example always have a date earlier than the next task 1 for the same `FacName`?

Comment: if you had your data in query 1 in a table (which you could do by writing to #temp table, but also using a WITH command), say the table is called T - you could then select the non-null  census rows from T - you could the CROSS APPLY to the first matching non null Cycle Drop for the empid

Comment: Also, should we assume that there will only ever be one record with a date value for each of the 5 date fields (`Census`, `Cycle Drop` etc.) within each cycle for each `FacName`? So we won't ever see two records with `Census` populated with a date that have the same `FacName` within the same cycle?

Comment: @3N1GM4 - No two cycles will never overlap... and yes to your second question as well..there will only be one record with a date value for each of the 5 date fields (Census, Cycle Drop etc.) within each cycle for each FacName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a CTE to label the cycles and then query out the relevant date values for each cycle with subqueries:

```
WITH tasksEnhanced (CurrentOccurrenceDate, TaskID, EmpID, FacName, Census, [Cycle Drop], [ECS and Print Label], [Inventory Preview], [Order and Receive Meds], cycleNum) AS
(
    SELECT  t1.*,
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM tasks t2 
                WHERE t1.FacName = t2.FacName 
                AND t1.TaskID = t2.TaskID 
                AND t2.CurrentOccurrenceDate < t1.CurrentOccurrenceDate
            ) + 1 AS cycleNum
    FROM tasks t1
)
SELECT DISTINCT
        te1.FacName,
        te1.cycleNum,
        (SELECT Census                   FROM tasksEnhanced census    WHERE census.FacName    = te1.FacName AND census.cycleNum    = te1.cycleNum AND census.Census                      IS NOT NULL) AS Census,
        (SELECT [Cycle Drop]             FROM tasksEnhanced cycleDrop WHERE cycleDrop.FacName = te1.FacName AND cycleDrop.cycleNum = te1.cycleNum AND cycleDrop.[Cycle Drop]             IS NOT NULL) AS [Cycle Drop],
        (SELECT [Inventory Preview]      FROM tasksEnhanced inv       WHERE inv.FacName       = te1.FacName AND inv.cycleNum       = te1.cycleNum AND inv.[Inventory Preview]            IS NOT NULL) AS [Inventory Preview],
        (SELECT [Order and Receive Meds] FROM tasksEnhanced orderMeds WHERE orderMeds.FacName = te1.FacName AND orderMeds.cycleNum = te1.cycleNum AND orderMeds.[Order and Receive Meds] IS NOT NULL) AS [Order and Receive Meds],
        (SELECT [ECS and Print Label]    FROM tasksEnhanced ECS       WHERE ECS.FacName       = te1.FacName AND ECS.cycleNum       = te1.cycleNum AND ECS.[ECS and Print Label]          IS NOT NULL) AS [ECS and Print Label]
FROM tasksEnhanced te1
ORDER BY te1.FacName, te1.cycleNum
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to modify your query to suit my needs...

Comment: Great, glad it was helpful to you, thanks for marking as accepted. Feel free to upvote as well if you found the answer useful.